How can I keep Xvfb screen is kept alive for crawler that is using chrome and selenium webdriver after ssh session is closed
I made a crawler program with selenium webdriver and chrome.
The target website blocks chrome headless mode, so I needed to use Xvfb.
The crawler works on AWS EC2 (Amazon linux2023).
While SSH session is keeping alive, the crawler works well.
Despite the program works in background, the crawler cannot connect to chrome after terminal for ssh is closed.
My goal is make the crawler program kept working after ssh session is closed.
(chrome need to be not headless)
Is it possible?
My current commands are below.
nohup Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1200x800x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
export DISPLAY=:1
nohup java -jar crawler.jar & ← this program stops after ssh session is closed.

